# HTML5/JS: Check video compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Does HTML5/JavaScript provide a function to check whether videos like `.mp4` can be checked. Then I could use a fallback to webm or even if the check for webm compatibility fails, another alternative could be pushed.

Are there features for checking compatibility implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following snippet:

```
/**
 * http://diveintohtml5.org/detect.html#video-formats
 */
function hasNativeMPEG4() {
      var v = document.createElement("video");

      if(!v.canPlayType) {
          return false;
      }
      // video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"
      var result = v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');

      if(result == "no" || result === "") {
          return false;
      } else {
          // "maybe", "probably"
          return true;
      }
}
```

... if it doesn't support MPEG4, then try to feed Flash fallback or WebM.

Comment: is this cross-browser compatible?

Comment: It is cross-browser compatible according to HTML5 spec. However: No warranty - you are responsible for testing it on your own sites. It has been working fine with our site with the latest browsers incl. mobile browsers. Please read the mentioned link for more information.